# Search for a string in a dynamic table using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a dynamic table with one column/field titled 'reference IDs'. The table is dynamic, however the column isn't. I want to grab all the reference IDs as strings.

Below is a snippet of the cell where the string 'reference ID' is. If you click on this cell it will sort the dynamic table in ascending or descending order (depending on how many clicks).

EDIT: have included the entire table header below

```
<th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="NUMBER_headerCell_2" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_2" abbr="Reference ID">
    <div id="NUMBER_column2_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Reference ID<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div>
</th>
```

I inspected the code and copied Xpath. I was trying to just see if I could click the reference ID cell so it would sort the list.

```
reports = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='NUMBER_headerCell_2']")
reports.click()
```

However, I get an error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
>   element:

I'm scratching my head a bit here. Not sure what to do. Any help would be much appreciated. :)

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="PagingGridLayout---checkbox">
            <div class="CheckboxGroup---choice_group CheckboxGroup---no_label CheckboxGroup---align_start" role="group">
                <div class="CheckboxGroup---choice_wrapper">
                    <div class="CheckboxGroup---choice_pair">
                        <input id="NUMBER_headerCell_selection_0" type="checkbox" value="0">
                        <label for="NUMBER_headerCell_selection_0" class="CheckboxGroup---choice_label"><span class="CheckboxGroup---accessibilityhidden">Select all rows</span></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="NUMBER_headerCell_0" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_0" abbr="Task Name">
            <div id="NUMBER_column0_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Task Name<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="NUMBER_headerCell_1" aria-sort="descending" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_1" abbr="Created On">
            <div id="NUMBER_column1_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Created On<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, sorted descending, activate to sort ascending</span></div>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="NUMBER_headerCell_2" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_2" abbr="Reference ID">
            <div id="NUMBER_column2_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Reference ID<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="NUMBER_headerCell_3" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_3" abbr="Assigned">
            <div id="NUMBER_column3_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Assigned<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="NUMBER_headerCell_4" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_4" abbr="Status">
            <div id="NUMBER_column4_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Status<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="NUMBER_headerCell_5" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_5" abbr="Task">
            <div id="NUMBER_column5_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Task<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="NUMBER_headerCell_6" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_6" abbr="Date">
            <div id="NUMBER_column6_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Date<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="NUMBER_headerCell_7" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_7" abbr="Delivery">
            <div id="NUMBER_column7_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text"> Delivery<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="NUMBER_headerCell_8" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---icon PagingGridLayout---center headCell_8" abbr="">
            <div id="NUMBER_column8_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text"><span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

EDIT 2: I think the table is in a field:

```
<div class="FieldLayout---field_layout"><div class="FieldLayout---accessibilityhidden"><span class="FieldLayout---field_label" id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362"></span></div><div class="FieldLayout---input_below"><div><div class="PagingGridLayout---scrollable_content"><table class="PagingGridLayout---table PagingGridLayout---scrollable PagingGridLayout---striped" aria-labelledby="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362"><thead><tr><th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_headerCell_0" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_0" abbr="Task Name"><div id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_column0_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Task Name<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div></th><th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_headerCell_1" aria-sort="ascending" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_1" abbr="Created On"><div id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_column1_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Created On<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, sorted ascending, activate to sort descending</span></div></th><th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_headerCell_2" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_2" abbr="Reference ID"><div id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_column2_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Reference ID<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div></th><th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_headerCell_3" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_3" abbr="Assigned To"><div id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_column3_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Assigned To<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div></th><th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_headerCell_4" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_4" abbr="Status"><div id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_column4_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Status<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div></th><th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_headerCell_5" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_5" abbr="Task Type"><div id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_column5_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Task Type<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div></th><th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_headerCell_6" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_6" abbr="Due Date"><div id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_column6_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">Due Date<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div></th><th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_headerCell_7" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---align_start headCell_7" abbr="State Delivery Region"><div id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_column7_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text">State Delivery Region<span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div></th><th tabindex="0" scope="col" id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_headerCell_8" aria-sort="none" class="PagingGridLayout---icon PagingGridLayout---center headCell_8" abbr=""><div id="303211e777b0011ec20d46df049f3362_column8_header" class="GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text"><span class="GridHeaderCell---accessibilityhidden">Sortable column, activate to sort ascending</span></div></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class=""><td class=""><div><p class="LinkGroup---link_group LinkGroup---align_start elements---global_p"><a href="https://nbnco.appiancloud.com/suite/sites/order-management/task/5654916" class="elements---global_a">Review Detailed Design</a></p></div></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">20/06/2019</p></td><td class=""><div><p class="LinkGroup---link_group LinkGroup---align_start elements---global_p"><a href="https://nbnco.appiancloud.com/suite/sites/order-management/page/home/record/lQBVF6bMMOMdjxUR6YqrUD8u9p8k-hS8unK9V9i437Bur4yN7zdzNRJSMWAdApXIql8ccBvoZkua3wEEaLPwmfrIt4hML7WksA3M31Jis9t50K6rVQ/view/summary" class="elements---global_a">ROR000000003458</a></p></div></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">RD Demand Deployment Design</p></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">In Progress</p></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">EE ORD</p></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">04/07/2019</p></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">VIC-TAS</p></td><td class=""><div data-thumbnail="false" class="ImageGroup---image_gallery ImageGroup---default_direction ImageGroup---center"><img class="DocumentImage---image DocumentImage---icon" src="https://nbnco.appiancloud.com/suite/rest/a/content/latest/ioBVF6bMMOMdjxUR68quAKs_DZLlxmi4D-ulyeD5psPvbhNnRNXNp4Jt80/custom/o;maxWidth=25;maxHeight=25" aria-label="20/06/2019 04:48 GMT+00:00; 04/07/2019 04:48 GMT+00:00; 7; 2; 8; 11 days 20 hours 45 minutes until due date" alt="20/06/2019 04:48 GMT+00:00; 04/07/2019 04:48 GMT+00:00; 7; 2; 8" tabindex="0"></div></td></tr><tr class=""><td class=""><div><p class="LinkGroup---link_group LinkGroup---align_start elements---global_p"><a href="https://nbnco.appiancloud.com/suite/sites/order-management/task/4574874" class="elements---global_a">Review Detailed Design</a></p></div></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">21/06/2019</p></td><td class=""><div><p class="LinkGroup---link_group LinkGroup---align_start elements---global_p"><a href="https://nbnco.appiancloud.com/suite/sites/order-management/page/home/record/lQBVF6bMMOMdjxUR6YqrUD8u9p8k-hS8unK9V9i437Bur4yN7zdzNRJSMWAdApXIql8ccBvoZkua3wEEaDBwWfrznT7V5_klxQu2CFX6LKxUlnS4dc/view/summary" class="elements---global_a">ROR000000001920</a></p></div></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">RD Demand Deployment Design</p></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">In Progress</p></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">EE ORD</p></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">05/07/2019</p></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">VIC-TAS</p></td><td class=""><div data-thumbnail="false" class="ImageGroup---image_gallery ImageGroup---default_direction ImageGroup---center"><img class="DocumentImage---image DocumentImage---icon" src="https://nbnco.appiancloud.com/suite/rest/a/content/latest/ioBVF6bMMOMdjxUR68quAKs_DZLlxmi4D-ulyeD5psPvbhNnRNXNp4Jt80/custom/o;maxWidth=25;maxHeight=25" aria-label="21/06/2019 04:38 GMT+00:00; 05/07/2019 04:38 GMT+00:00; 7; 2; 8; 12 days 20 hours 35 minutes until due date" alt="21/06/2019 04:38 GMT+00:00; 05/07/2019 04:38 GMT+00:00; 7; 2; 8" tabindex="0"></div></td></tr><tr class=""><td class=""><div><p class="LinkGroup---link_group LinkGroup---align_start elements---global_p"><a href="https://nbnco.appiancloud.com/suite/sites/order-management/task/4618136" class="elements---global_a">Review Detailed Design</a></p></div></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">21/06/2019</p></td><td class=""><div><p class="LinkGroup---link_group LinkGroup---align_start elements---global_p"><a href="https://nbnco.appiancloud.com/suite/sites/order-management/page/home/record/lQBVF6bMMOMdjxUR6YqrUD8u9p8k-hS8unK9V9i437Bur4yN7zdzNRJSMWAdApXIql8ccBvoZkua3wEEaPExWfrqRY8d7Vgkjhl0wj8YwGA6aNQ1m4/view/summary" class="elements---global_a">ROR000000002132</a></p></div></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">RD Demand Deployment Design</p></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">In Progress</p></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">EE ORD</p></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">05/07/2019</p></td><td class=""><p class="ParagraphText---richtext_paragraph ParagraphText---default_direction ParagraphText---align_start elements---global_p">VIC-TAS</p></td><td class=""><div data-thumbnail="false" class="ImageGroup---image_gallery ImageGroup---default_direction ImageGroup---center"><img class="DocumentImage---image DocumentImage---icon" src="https://nbnco.appiancloud.com/suite/rest/a/content/latest/ioBVF6bMMOMdjxUR68quAKs_DZLlxmi4D-ulyeD5psPvbhNnRNXNp4Jt80/custom/o;maxWidth=25;maxHeight=25" aria-label="21/06/2019 06:03 GMT+00:00; 05/07/2019 06:03 GMT+00:00; 7; 2; 8; 12 days 22 hours 0 minutes until due date" alt="21/06/2019 06:03 GMT+00:00; 05/07/2019 06:03 GMT+00:00; 7; 2; 8" tabindex="0"></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Check if table is inside `iframe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can  not comment, I have to do this here.

Idea- 1 Choose the parent node. For example the **th** you are trying to access is inside a class. Grab that class element `grab_class= br.find_elements_by_class('class_name')`
and then find the elements in it like `grab_elements=grab_class.find_elements_by_(anything you feel like)`

Idea-1 Grab all the Thead/Th elements in the page and manually access the list. let us suppose the element you want is 5th , then choose lis[4] and operate on it.

Just a rough sketch of what can be done. I hope it'll be useful.

`NOTE` Be careful when finding elements. `find_element` gives a single and first object matching criteria where `find_elemments` returns a list of all the WebElements.

Comment: Hey @Mahesh that was a really great explination! Thanks! I implemented the code and now I get an error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_id'

Comment: Do it on the objects. Do it with list[i]

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean sorry

Comment: @says When you perform ```find_elements_by``` , it returns a list containing all the WebElements. Just pick the class,tag,id one by one until you reach the child node. For the analogy, it is just like that  when you go to a friend's home abroad you have to ask for country first, then ask for the State  then it follows until you reach someone's home.

Comment: Pick the parent class first, then locate all the ```thead``` then inside it, locate your element.

Comment: grab_refid = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('elements---global_a')

for i in grab_refid:
    print (i)

Comment: The above code is what I've used. It prints out: selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="NUMBER", element="NUMBER2")> instead of the actual reference number. The reference ID numbers in the table are hyperlinks with their own href

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the ID of the element, maybe you're better off using:

```
reports = browser.find_element_by_id('NUMBER_headerCell_2')
reports.click()
```

See if that works!

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error saying 'NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:' ... I put a time.sleep(20) before that line to see if it was a loading issue but that didn't fix it

Comment: Hmm that's odd! Would you mind posting the rest of the HTML code? If it's huge then at least the portion surrounding the tag you're trying to click

Comment: edited my OP with the html for the entire header at the bottom of the post :)

Comment: Okay try, just for the sake of testing, to set time.sleep(60) instead of 20, and see what happens. It isn't good practice, as it's probably better to set an [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), but let's give the page a whole minute to load

Comment: Tried that also, still not having any luck

Comment: Is your table in a frame or iframe of any sort?

Comment: I'm not sure? Like I can inspect each element of the table

Answer (score 1):

To handle use `WebdriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable` and following xpath to click on the element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='NUMBER_column2_header'][contains(.,'Reference ID')]"))).click()
```

You need to use following imports to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I have those imports. I tried the line of code at the top but got a timeout exception

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "th.PagingGridLayout---align_start[abbr='Reference ID'] > div.GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//th[contains(@class, 'PagingGridLayout---align_start') and @abbr='Reference ID']/div[@class='GridHeaderCell---grid_header_text']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```